I can't deploy the rest-builder module (Liferay 7.4)
The rest-builder module is created without problem in the “modules” folder of the workspace with the following command: blade create -t rest-builder demo-rest-builder
Next I refresh the gradle of the project, the rest-builder module is shown in the project explorer without any problem.

In the “rest-openapi.yaml” file I have added the following code:

info:
    description: "DemoRestBuilder REST API"
    license:
        name: "Apache 2.0"
        url: "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html"
    title: "DemoRestBuilder"
    version: v1.0
openapi: 3.0.1
paths:
  "/get-usuario":
    get:
      operationId: getUsuarioById
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: usuarioId
          required: true
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int64
      responses:
        200:
          description: "Success Response"
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                items:
                  $ref: "#/components/schemas/UsuarioEntidad"
            application/xml:
              schema:
                items:
                  $ref: "#/components/schemas/UsuarioEntidad"
      tags: ["Usuario"]
components:
  schemas:
    UsuarioEntidad:
      properties:
        usuarioId:
          type: integer
          format: int64

The following command is then executed in the “demo-rest-builder” module path: blade gw buildREST
The project's gradle is then refreshed, where the following packages will be automatically created:

Finally, the following command is executed: blade gw deploy
An error occurs in the “BaseUsuarioResourceImpl” class because it is importing the deprecated class “TransformUtil”.


Trace error in rest builder module deployment

Task :modules:demo-rest-builder:demo-rest-builder-impl:compileJava FAILED
/Projects/Liferay_Projects/compania_ficticia/compania_ficticia_repositorio/compania-ficticia-workspace/modules/demo-rest-builder/demo-rest-builder-impl/src/main/java/demo/rest/builder/internal/resource/v1_0/BaseUserResourceImpl.java:259: error: no suitable method found for transform(T#1[],UnsafeFunction<T#1,R#1,Exception>,Class<CAP#1>)
return TransformUtil.transform(array, unsafeFunction, clazz);
^
method TransformUtil.<T#2,R#2,E#1>transform(Collection<T#2>,UnsafeFunction<T#2,R#2,E#1>) is not applicable
(cannot infer type-variable(s) T#2,R#2,E#1
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
method TransformUtil.<R#3,E#2>transform(int[],UnsafeFunction<Integer,R#3,E#2>,Class) is not applicable
(cannot infer type-variable(s) R#3,E#2
(argument mismatch; T#1[] cannot be converted to int[]))
method TransformUtil.transform(long[],UnsafeFunction,Class) is not applicable
(cannot infer type-variable(s) R#4,E#3
(argument mismatch; T#1[] cannot be converted to long[]))
method TransformUtil.transform(T#3[],UnsafeFunction,Class) is not applicable
(inference variable R#5 has incompatible bounds
equality constraints: R#1
lower bounds: CAP#1)
where T#1,R#1,T#2,R#2,E#1,R#3,E#2,R#4,E#3,T#3,R#5,E#4 are type-variables:
T#1 extends Object declared in method transform(T#1[],UnsafeFunction,Class)
R#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1,R#1>transform(T#1[],UnsafeFunction<T#1,R#1,Exception>,Class)
T#2 extends Object declared in method transform(Collection,UnsafeFunction)
R#2 extends Object declared in method transform(Collection,UnsafeFunction)
E#1 extends Throwable declared in method transform(Collection,UnsafeFunction)
R#3 extends Object declared in method transform(int[],UnsafeFunction,Class)
E#2 extends Throwable declared in method transform(int[],UnsafeFunction,Class)
R#4 extends Object declared in method transform(long[],UnsafeFunction,Class)
E#3 extends Throwable declared in method transform(long[],UnsafeFunction,Class)
T#3 extends Object declared in method transform(T#3[],UnsafeFunction,Class)
R#5 extends Object declared in method transform(T#3[],UnsafeFunction,Class)
E#4 extends Throwable declared in method transform(T#3[],UnsafeFunction,Class)
where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
/Projects/Liferay_Projects/compania_ficticia/compania_ficticia_repositorio/compania-ficticia-workspace/modules/demo-rest-builder/demo-rest-builder-impl/src/main/java/demo/rest/builder/internal/resource/v1_0/BaseUserResourceImpl.java:266: error: method transformToArray in class TransformUtil cannot be applied to given types;
return TransformUtil.transformToArray(
^
required: Collection,UnsafeFunction,Class
found: Collection,UnsafeFunction,Class
reason: inference variable R#1 has incompatible bounds
equality constraints: R#2
lower bounds: CAP#1
where T#1,R#1,E,T#2,R#2 are type-variables:
T#1 extends Object declared in method transformToArray(Collection,UnsafeFunction,Class)
R#1 extends Object declared in method transformToArray(Collection,UnsafeFunction,Class)
E extends Throwable declared in method transformToArray(Collection,UnsafeFunction,Class)
T#2 extends Object declared in method transformToArray(Collection,UnsafeFunction,Class)
R#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2,R#2>transformToArray(Collection<T#2>,UnsafeFunction<T#2,R#2,Exception>,Class<?>)
where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
Note: /Projects/Liferay_Projects/compania_ficticia/compania_ficticia_repositorio/compania-ficticia-workspace/modules/demo-rest-builder/demo-rest-builder-impl/src/main/java/demo/rest/builder/internal/resource/v1_0/BaseUserResourceImpl.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':modules:demo-rest-builder:demo-rest-builder-impl:compileJava'.


Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.


What solution could be applied to this?
What am I doing wrong?

